# Facebook callback "like status" for fanpage

Tags: facebook, callback, facebook-page

How can I get info about "if I liked the facebook fanpage"?
The best for me will be ajax request with callback, but I've not found anywhere the solution.

Comment: From within a page tab app, you’ll find that info in the `signed_request` parameter. From anywhere else, you have to have the user connect to your app, get their permission to read their likes, and then check `/userid/likes/pageid` via the API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a page tab app, FB already tells you if the user is a fan of that page automatically from the signed request. I think it's called "is_fan". The nice thing about this is that it does not even require the user to install your tab before hand.

If you are making a canvas or standalone app, then you need to

- Ask user to install your app with "user_likes" permission because you need to check their likes
- Then do a Graph API call to /me/likes/{page_id} - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

This method is a bit long winded and you will usually encounter a drop off rate from users because you are asking an extended permission (user_likes) but if you have the right user flow it could work out.